# when creating a cookie, how can I specify www and no www cookie?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

when I create a cookie for a domain, is it possible for me to set that this domain should be on both the www and non www domain?

I check for a cookie, and if not present I rediret to login page (its not a super secure thing).  it seems when the user has a cookie, if the url changes to www. it gets redirected to login again.

Answer (score 5):

When you drop the cookie specify .mydomain.com - note the leading period. That should work for both the root domain and the www subdomain.

Answer (score 2):

@electronherders' solution works, but you should also consider canonicalising either the www or the no-www domain. Redirect visitors from one to the other, so there's only one correct URL for your site.